# generate the waveform of chords in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

> I want to generate the waveform of chords in Java (Android).
>  The
>   following is an example of a sine wave chord (C, E, G).
>   I would
>   like to create waves of Square, Triangle, Sawtooth ,
>  but it is
>   difficult. 
>  can someone tell me an answer?

```
// sine wave
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT,
        44100,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
byte[] sinWave = new byte[44100];

double freq_c3 = 261.6256;
double freq_e3 = 329.6276;
double freq_g3 = 391.9954;
double t = 0.0;
double dt = 1.0 / 44100;

for (int i = 0; i < sinWave.length; i++, t += dt) {
    double sum = Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * t * freq_c3)
            + Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * t * freq_e3)
            + Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * t * freq_g3);
    sinWave[i] = (byte) (Byte.MAX_VALUE * (sum / 3));
}
track.write(sinWave, 0, sinWave.length);
```